# Can't manage to print "None" with beautifulsoup: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to find a solution in questions found here but could not find one that would give me some kind of solution or a similar approach to my problem. I'm very new to python and as a first step I wanted to learn how to scrape data from IMDB using beautiful soup. I want to scrape the name of movie, IMDB rating and number of votes. There are some movies in the list that do not have rating and number of votes and I'm getting: Thanks so much for all your comments. The complete Traceback is the following:
    Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File 
"C:/Users/nmartine/PycharmProjects/ratings_ScraperMetracritic/venv/ratings_ScraperMetacritic.py", line 24, in  votes = container.find('span', attrs= {'name':'nv'})['data-value'] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable '  in my output when python does not found the rating or votes. I'm getting the name of the titles correctly but I want the output to return a "None" if the title does not have IMDB or number of votes. This is my code so far:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2014-01-01,2018-12-31&count=250&page=3&sort=moviemeter,asc&ref_=adv_nxt'  
response = get(url)  
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')  
type(html_soup)

program_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'lister-item mode- 
advanced')
print(len(program_containers))

for container in program_containers:

name = container.h3.a.text
print(name)

if (container.strong):
    imdb = float(container.strong.text)
    print(imdb)
else: 'None'

votes = container.find('span', attrs= {'name':'nv'})['data-value']
print(votes)
```

Hope someone can help me! Thanks!

Comment: 1. Format your code (the `for` loop is syntactically incorrect). 2. Include the _complete_ error message.

Comment: Is program_containers ever `None`?

Comment: no, all the info of the movies are inside a container

Comment: Is there a reason this need to be a one-liner? Why not just `nv = container.find('span', attrs= {'name':'nv'})` then `if nv: votes = nv['data-value']`? (I'm  guessing about where the error happens and why, but it should be obvious how to change it if I've guessed wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing `'data-value'` appears to be causing the current issue, since `find('span', attrs= {'name':'nv'})` has to return a `BeautifulSoup` object for `['data-value']` to be successful. However, instead of `'data-value'`, the `text` attribute can be used, along with `getattr`. `getattr` will attempt to access the `text` attribute from the result of `find('span', attrs= {'name':'nv'})`, however, if the latter is `None` (which does not have a `text` attribute), `None` itself will be returned, being first specified as a third parameter in `getattr`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests, re
from typing import NamedTuple
class Movie(NamedTuple):
  title:str
  rating:str
  votes:str

def get_films(placeholder=None):
  d = soup(requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2014-01-01,2018-12-31&count=250&page=3&sort=moviemeter,asc&ref_=adv_nxt').text, 'html.parser')
  films = [i for i in d.find_all('div', {'class':re.compile('lister-item[\w\W]+')})]
  final_films = [[getattr(i.find(*c), 'text', placeholder) for c in [['a'], ['strong'], ['span', {'name':'nv'}]]] for i in films] 
  return [Movie(a, b, c) for a, b, c in final_films if a != ' \n']

new_films = get_films()
```

First ten elements in `new_films`:

```
[Movie(title='The OA', rating='7.8', votes='54,496'), Movie(title='Parmanu: The Story of Pokhran', rating='8.5', votes='4,116'), Movie(title='Batman Ninja', rating='5.7', votes='6,847'), Movie(title='Verónica', rating='6.2', votes='20,634'), Movie(title='Set It Up', rating=None, votes=None), Movie(title='Wynonna Earp', rating='7.5', votes='11,771'), Movie(title='Spectre', rating='6.8', votes='333,593'), Movie(title='Van Helsing', rating='6.0', votes='10,719'), Movie(title='The Year of Spectacular Men', rating='6.6', votes='64'), Movie(title='The Heretics', rating='4.8', votes='298')]
```

Notice that for some movies on the list, rating and votes are not listed, and this solution simply provides `None` in its place:

```
[Movie(title="Tom Clancy's Jack Ryan", rating=None, votes=None)]
```

Comment: Without the traceback, it's hard to be sure, but it looks like the OP's error comes from doing `['data-value']` on a failed `find`, not on calling `.text` on a failed `find`. (After all, it's a "not subscriptable" TypeError, not an AttributeError.) So, `getattr` is solving a different problem that the OP isn't asking about, and just making things more complicated, without explaining how to solve the OP's (likely) actual problem.

Comment: @abarnert I do think you are right regarding `['data-value']`, and I added an alternative method to access the votes value from the HTML. `getattr` makes it much simpler to handle the occasions when `None` is returned as a result of `BeautifulSoup.find` (which is the OP's problem), and when it is necessary to access the `text` attribute. That being said, perhaps my explanation in the answer itself is misleading. Updating....

Comment: I don't think it's possible to write a better answer without more response from the OP, so I wouldn't waste too much time on it…

Comment: Thanks so much for all your comments. The complete Traceback is the following: 
 Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/nmartine/PycharmProjects/ratings_ScraperMetracritic/venv/ratings_ScraperMetacritic.py", line 24, in <module> votes = container.find('span', attrs= {'name':'nv'})['data-value'] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @NMM That is because `None` does not have a `__getitem__` method, which makes subscripting possible. Did the code posted in the answer above work for you?